# How to end a process using inno setup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, uninstallation, windows, kill-process

I want to  kill a process using inno setup.i want to check whether the window is open before i start installing the setup.

can i do this by searching windows name?
please help me with some sample code to kill the process

Comment: Perhaps a simple mutex solution would be sufficient? Add a mutex to your application, and then use the `AppMutex` parameter in the `Setup` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to use a mutex to see if it's still running using `AppMutex`. One way to close it is to find the window handle then just post a simple WM_CLOSE message.

There are other options like the [Files in use extension](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Files_in_use_extension) and [PSVince](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Call_psvince.dll_on_install_and_uninstall)

Also see [this article](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Detect_if_an_application_is_running) for a bit more information.

Comment: begin
Wnd := FindWindowByWindowName('name');
if Wnd <> 0 then SendMessage(Wnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
Result := True;.                                                    i tried like this.it is working fine but i want to close the tray window.how to quit this window

Comment: [UninstallRun]
Filename: {cmd}; parameters: /c taskkill /f /im notepad.exe;Flags: runhidden.can i do like this?

Comment: Don't just kill it outright as it can cause problems. Use a hidden window and the FindWindow method to notify it to shut down.

Answer (score 19):

in the [UninstallRun] section, you can add the following code:

```
Filename: {sys}\taskkill.exe; Parameters: "/f /im MyProcess.exe"; Flags: skipifdoesntexist runhidden
```

Comment: Why [UninstallRun]? The OP wanted to kill the process before running the setup. Isn't [UninstallRun] invoked when the uninstaller runs?

Answer (score 8):

This is something I did to prompt the user to close a program if it was found running.

```
function CheckProcessRunning( aProcName,
                              aProcDesc: string ): boolean;
var
  ShellResult: boolean;
  ResultCode: integer;
  cmd: string;
  sl: TStringList;
  f: string;
  d: string;
begin
  cmd := 'for /f "delims=," %%i ' + 
         'in (''tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq ' + aProcName + '" /FO CSV'') ' + 
         'do if "%%~i"=="' + aProcName + '" exit 1'; 
  f := 'CheckProc.cmd';
  d := AddBackSlash( ExpandConstant( '{tmp}' ));
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  sl.Add( cmd );
  sl.Add( 'exit /0' );
  sl.SaveToFile( d + f );
  sl.Free;
  Result := true;
  while ( Result ) do
  begin
    ResultCode := 1;
    ShellResult := Exec( f,
                         '',
                         d, 
                         SW_HIDE, 
                         ewWaitUntilTerminated, 
                         ResultCode );
    Result := ResultCode > 0;
    if Result and 
       ( MsgBox( aProcDesc + ' is running. This program must be closed to continue.'#13#10 + 
                 'Please close it and click Yes to retry or click No to cancel this installer.', 
                 mbConfirmation, 
                 MB_YESNO ) <> IDYES ) then
      Break;
  end;
  DeleteFile( d + f );
end;
```

I used it in the following special code sections as follows:

```
// Perform some initializations.  Return False to abort setup
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  // Do not use any user defined vars in here such as {app}
  InitializeGlobals;
  Result := not ( CheckProcessRunning( 'bcb.exe',      'C++ Builder' ) or
                  CheckProcessRunning( 'delphi32.exe', 'Delphi'      ) or
                  CheckProcessRunning( 'bds.exe',      'Rad Studio'  ));
end;


function InitializeUninstall: Boolean;
begin
  InitializeGlobals;
  Result := not ( CheckProcessRunning( 'bcb.exe',      'C++ Builder' ) or
                  CheckProcessRunning( 'delphi32.exe', 'Delphi'      ) or
                  CheckProcessRunning( 'bds.exe',      'Rad Studio'  ));
end;
```

Comment: The way it's meant to be. Always ask the user nicely to close the application.

Comment: Love this; except in the current version InitializeGlobals; breaks it.

Answer (score 1):

A less complicated method would be to run a [batch file](http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?runbatchfile) which uses task kill

ie: if you wanted to kill notepad before uninstalling

```
taskkill /IM notepad.exe
```